# ImageView пустеет при методе setImageDrawable

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-studio, activity

Здравствуйте. 
У меня в приложении при нажатии на `ImageView` картина должна измениться. Вызываю метод `setImageDrawable(Drawable d)`, но эмулятор показывает пустую картину. С ресурсом все в порядке (файл PNG, который познается приложением), приложение запускается без проблем.

Отрывки кода:

```
ImageView i11, i12; 
Drawable[] pictures = new Drawable[12];
```

В методе onCreate:

```
i11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s11); 
i11.setOnClickListener(this); 
i12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s12); 
i12.setOnClickListener(this); 
pictures[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tools10);
```

В методе `onClick`:

```
if (v.getId()==R.id.s11) 
    i11.setImageDrawable(pictures[0]); 
if (v.getId()==R.id.s12) 
    i12.setImageDrawable(pictures[0]);
```

Отрывок layout файла (верхняя строка, где 3 вопросительных знака):

```
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/s11" 
        android:layout_width="80dp" 
        android:layout_height="80dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:src="@drawable/qm" /> 

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/s12" 
        android:layout_width="80dp" 
        android:layout_height="80dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:src="@drawable/qm" /> 

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/s13" 
        android:layout_width="80dp" 
        android:layout_height="80dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:src="@drawable/qm" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Запускается нормально, нажимаю на вопр. знак, а картины нет. Может дело в памяти или что-нибудь еще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На первый взгляд ошибок нема. Разве что вы везде по клику одну и туже картинку показываете. Так и должно быть: `.setImageDrawable(pictures[0]); `?

Comment: Да. Это просто для тестирования.
Сначала много хлопот получилось насчет загрузки картинок в папку res, не совпадал формат, либо картинки были PNG, но приложение не познавало их при инициализации (не виднелся thumbnail слева от кода). Затем подобрал картинки, но они не появляются при нажатии.

Comment: А если не из массива а напрямую из ресурсов: `setImageResource(R.drawable.tools10)`?

Comment: Возможно проблема  ваших картинках. Попробуйте просто иконку приложения показать `setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложно так сходу сказать, причин может быть много.

1. Проверьте в `onCreate`, у вас `getDrawable` не `null` возвращает?
2. Подозреваю, что `null`. Тогда после этого проверьте ваши папки ресурсов. В какой папке у вас файл лежит? Возможно изображение есть в папках типа drawable-hdpi/drawable-ldpi, но нет в той, которая используется для текущего разрешения экрана. Поместите изображение в дефолтную папку drawable, чтоб такого не было.
3. Бывает, что изображение само по себе битое. Да, даже если вы в каком-то редакторе можете просматривать его нормально, `getDrawable` всё равно может вернуть `null`. Попробуйте временно заменить изображение другим и проверить.

Comment: Все, исправил. У Drawable ссылка не из того места была поэтому ни на что она не ссылалась.
Теперь все картинки открываются, даже те у которых thumbnail не появляется.